# How does Spree Fancy theme turn the expiration field into month / year selects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I understand the basic methods of customising spree (deface, overriding view files, etc). I can't figure out how Spree Fancy theme replaces the credit card expiration input text field with month / year select fields.

There doesn't appear to be any deface overrides, or view overrides, or javascript, that influences that field.

Here's the payment deface overrides: https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/tree/2-0-stable/app/overrides/spree/checkout/_payment

And here's the main js file: https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/2-0-stable/app/assets/javascripts/store/spree_fancy.js

There are no entire view overrides relevant to the payment process: https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/tree/2-0-stable/app/views/spree

Anyone know how it's done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spree 2-0-stable uses select boxes for these:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-0-stable/frontend/app/views/spree/checkout/payment/_gateway.html.erb#L17-L18

They're not overridden, and appear as select boxes in the default theme, not just spree_fancy.